# Windows recipe organizer that can import from Living Cookbook

Tags: windows, cooking

I am looking for a Windows 10 recipe organizer that meets these requirements:

1. Can import from Living Cookbook files.
2. Can *export* in a format that has a reasonable chance of being imported by other recipe programs.
3. Can print to 4-by-6 index cards.
4. Can tag each recipe with multiple categories.
5. Can import recipes from web sites.